# Can you/is this the correct way to add an even listener to an <HTML>/<body> tag?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make a function to check, anytime something is changed on my page, if all input is valid.  I thought the best way to do this, rather than attach the function to every input would be to put it on the entire page (hence html/body tag,) but this didn't seem to work in that nothing happened.  My code looks like:

```
<body onchange="removewarn()">
.
form elements
.
.
</body>
```

and the function

```
function removewarn(){

if(all input is valid)
{
document.getElementById('warning').style.visibility="hidden";
}
}
```

The point of which, is to remove a warning put on the page if all elements are not filled in or are not valid.

Comment: I think your idea is ok but I doubt the body "onchange" handler is the right mechanism.  Consider using a keypress handler instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `onchange` event is only supported by inputs, selects and textareas, wich is why your function will never be called if you try to bind it to the body tag.

You will either have to bind it on every input, or to use something like [jQuery's delegate method](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/).

Comment: Then my question is: can you have more than one "onchange" event on a single form element?

Comment: Yes, but the best way would probably be to bind one single function to the onchange event and have this function call other functions if you need to separate your logic in different functions.

Answer (score 1):

The onchange event does only work with Form elements, so you will have to add it to every form element. However! there is a easier and cleaner way to do this than doing it inline:

```
for(i=0; i<document.FormName.elements.length; i++)//gets all the elements of your form.
{
    document.FormName.elements[i].onchange = removewarn();//adds the removewarn function to the onchange handler of this element.
}
```